# ExtJS form creation on fly for page redirect

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am using 4.2.1 extjs version. I have view which is extended from ext.container. which is read only/dispaly. No input is taken in this screen. Now i need to redirect to another page though HTTP POST request with some parameter, I need to do form submit on click of a button.

1. do i need to create  form on fly to do form submit? if yes how i can do. OR
2. I can create form and have item as button and do form submit on click of button ?

Parameters i need to pass in form are not input fields. I will be having the values already with me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var data = {
    firstName: "Shweta",
    lastName: "Upadhya"
};
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    url: 'https://www.google.de',
    defaultType: 'hiddenfield',
    jsonSubmit: false,
    method: 'GET',
    standardSubmit: true,
    hidden: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
Ext.Object.each(data, function (dataKey, dataValue) {
    form.add({
        xtype: 'hiddenfield',
        name: dataKey,
        value: dataValue
    });
}, this);
form.submit();
```